# 3D Rotation where the z-axis remains vertical

Tags: javascript, 3d, rotation

[This codepen](https://codepen.io/SitePoint/pen/VeEyvm?editors=0010) has a small rotation function that accepts theta and phi values. The formula of the rotation can be found anywhere on the internet and is fairly simple:

```js
function rotate(P, C, theta, phi) {
    let ct = Math.cos(theta);
    let st = Math.sin(theta);
    let cp = Math.cos(phi);
    let sp = Math.sin(phi);

    let x = P.x - C.x;
    let y = P.y - C.y;
    let z = P.z - C.z;

    P.x = ct * x - st * cp * y + st * sp * z + C.x;
    P.y = st * x + ct * cp * y - ct * sp * z + C.y;
    P.z = sp * y + cp * z + C.z;
}
```

This rotation works as a demonstration, but It's easy to loose track of which face of the cube is the initially bottom face.

[openSCAD](https://github.com/openscad/openscad) on the other hand has a very nice rotation where the z-axis of the object always appears as a vertical line:

[image: Cube rotated around the z axis]

The above function would behave the same, if you'd only change the `theta` value. As soon as you change `phi` value the cube stars to fall over.

How would I write such a rotation in JavaScript?

Comment: The z axis of the object is not always vertical (it cannot be vertical if you are seeing some of the bottom face for example). Please show code you have already tried.

Comment: so far, I only fiddled with a function identical to the one in the codepen.

Comment: sorry, I don't know how to describe the difference. What are we looking at? In openSCAD i see that the z-axis always goes top to bottom or bottom to top. no tilting. that's what I mean

Comment: the z-axis only tilts in the direction of the camera

Comment: It tilts if you look at the x, y, z indicator on the left, though it’s quite difficult to see. Anyway, I guess we can describe it as the bottom and top faces remaining top and bottom?